# How can I call my shinyapp through functions?

Tags: r, shiny

I deployed a shiny app as a library. I want to know how to open a file in my shiny app but through an R function.

I mean; I want to have two different functions:

1. **open(fileName)** This function will open the shiny app with the file that the user will send as a parameter.
2. **create()**  This function will open the shiny app with a new file

I am confused about how can I organize my application. For example, if the user types open(Test1), then deploy my app with the file Test1 loaded or what happened if the user types create().

Do I need to create different scripts of app.R and then inside each function call the app.R that will help me with the behavior expected?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible example would help to understand your exact needs (e.g., what do you mean exactly by "open a file"), but here is something that I think will get you started.

This is based on the first Shiny example provided [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html). Basically the entire shiny app is defined inside of a function called `gadget_runner()`, and the app is then run at the end of the function with `shiny::runGadget(ui, server)`. You can define the function to operate in different manners based on the arguments passed. Then you could define your functions `open(fileName)` and `create()` to call the function as desired.

```
gadget_runner <- function(fileName) {
  if (missing(fileName)) {
    x <- tempfile()
  }

  ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::titlePanel(x),
    shiny::sidebarLayout(
      shiny::sidebarPanel(
        shiny::sliderInput(
          inputId = "bins",
          label = "Number of bins:",
          min = 1,
          max = 50,
          value = 30
        )
      ),
      shiny::mainPanel(
        shiny::plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- shiny::renderPlot({
      x <- faithful$waiting
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
      hist(x,
        breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
        xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
        main = "Histogram of waiting times"
      )
    })
  }

  shiny::runGadget(ui, server)
}

open <- function(fileName) {
  gadget_runner(fileName)
}

create <- function() {
  gadget_runner()
}
```